# cause of excessively large application.js file in public/packs for rails app? / rack timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, webpacker

My app has been throwing frequent rack timeout errors, and i think i narrowed the problem down to the size of the compiled javascript file. **public/packs/application-5db30a18f8715133f889.js** is 2.1mb. this is not doable!

something to note is i have two asset folders: one for sprockets where all my css and most js is, and one for webpacker, which i added solely to use an image upload node package called Upp. i intend to move to webpacker completely, but not yet. this is my **app/assets/application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require cable
//= require_tree ./channels
//= require semantic-ui/dist/semantic
//= require micromodal/dist/micromodal
//= require local-time
//= require micromodal
//= require init
```

and this is **app/webpacker/packs/application.js**:

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
import fileUpload from 'fileUpload'
    document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.upload-file').forEach(fileInput => {
        fileUpload(fileInput)
      })
    })
```

am i doing something wrong in **app/assets/application.js** that would cause such a huge file size?

This is what webpacker shows in console btw:

```
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 5357ms
Built at: 03/01/2021 12:16:43 AM
                                             Asset       Size  Chunks                                Chunk Names
            js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js    737 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  [big]  application
js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.LICENSE.txt   1.08 KiB          [emitted]                     
         js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.br    135 KiB          [emitted]                     
         js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.gz    182 KiB          [emitted]                     
        js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.map   2.16 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]               application
     js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.map.br    424 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
     js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.map.gz    558 KiB          [emitted]              [big]  
                                     manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]                     
                                  manifest.json.br  129 bytes          [emitted]                     
                                  manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]                     
Entrypoint application [big] = js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js js/application-62fd5a37239b6e18973d.js.map
```

worth mentioning that i don't have a `webpacker.config.js`. should i?

Bundle Analyzer screenshot:
[image]

Comment: If you have other files in the packs folder, you should take them out. Webpack will create a pack for each one of these and they compound upon each other.

Comment: super helpful thank u!!

Comment: Glad it helped. I didn't turn it into an answer because I can't explain what webpack's process is here, but it for sure makes for bigger js bundles when you have more files in there. I think the original stimulus documentation had you putting the controllers in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say the problem is from the `packs/application`, I would add https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer to see what webpacker is adding in that file.

Here is how my `webpack/development.js` looks like:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const environment = require('./environment');

environment.plugins.append('BundleAnalyzerPlugin', new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());

...
```

Everything else is pretty straightforward. Look at the new tab that's pops up when you start webpacker and hover over its contents.

**Update**

`uppy` seems to loaded twice. Keeping one version should decrease the bundle size. If that's not enough then you could look into [Lazy Loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/), [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and https://loadable-components.com/docs/library-splitting/. Ideally you should load the file-upload logic only on the pages that is required. Seeing it in `packs/application` tells me that you are loading in on every page.

Comment: yes!!! this is super helpful, thank you. so it would appear to be ....node_modules. only ONE of the js files that make up application.js are minified. why is it using unminified code?

Comment: In development it doesn't minify unless you start webpacker with NODE_ENV=production. Some packages from node_modules have .min files which are probably used by default, I think. In my case I explicitly call in some cases require('abc.min.js').

Comment: hmmm it's even bigger with the production env. i did that and added webpacker's console output to my op T_T

Comment: I see it 737 KiB. Don't look at the `.map` row. Add a screenshot from bundle analyzer. Maybe you could remove some unused js or split the bundle (lazy load stuff)

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: uppy seems to be the larger one. I suggest loading it "lazy" only where you need it. Some docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/, https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/. An example: `import(/* webpackChunkName: "uppy" */ 'uppy')` which will create a separate chunk.

Comment: @calyxofheld Do you need both `@uppy` and `uppy.min`? Keep just `uupy.min` and the bundle should decrease dramatically.

Comment: hmm how very odd. i wonder how i am using both? i have a `fileUpload.js` in my webpacker folder, and that has `import 'uppy/dist/uppy.min.css'` and then imports `Core, Dashboard, Form, Informer, ProgressBar, ThumbnailGenerator, AwsS3`. my package.json has `"@uppy/image-editor": "0.2.0",
, "uppy": "^1.26.0", "@uppy/dashboard": "^1.17.0", "@uppy/core": "^1.16.1"`. i need all of those for image uploads to work.

Comment: turns out i only need `"uppy": "^1.26.0"` but even then removing the others has no big impact :(

Comment: There's not much you can do with these big packages. My only suggestion is to lazy load it, split it into chunks and load them only where they're needed. I doubt it you need the file upload on all pages. I can update the answer with what I said if you want..

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks!